# Is it possible to handle screensaver event from flash file?

Tags: actionscript-3, screensaver

I have created a flash file, which will play another scene and will stop on mouse over. Then i converted this to a screensaver format.But i need to put a delay on mouse over before the screensaver will disappear .

Answer (score 2):

By using fs commands i can ignore/ accept mouse events.

For example :

fscommand("mousequit","variable_name");
The value "0" means that the screensaver is set to quit on mouse events, "1" means it ignores mouse events.

I can ignore the mouse events until i reached the expected frame.So i can give a delay or what ever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Event.ACTIVATE/Event.DEACTIVATE events for handling app focus.

```
private function addActivationEvents():void
{
    addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE, handleAppActivationEvent);
    addEventListener(flash.events.Event.DEACTIVATE, handleAppActivationEvent);
}

private function handleAppActivationEvent(event:flash.events.Event):void
{
    switch (event.type)
    {
        case flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE:
            break;
        case flash.events.Event.DEACTIVATE:
            break;
    }
}
```